# Configuring mqttConnect Options in Meteor for CloudMQTT

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, mqtt

I'm trying to use the Meteor package [perak:meteor-mqtt-collection](https://github.com/perak/meteor-mqtt-collection/) to connect to [CloudMQTT](https://www.cloudmqtt.com/), but am unsure about how to interpret the syntax for the [mqttConnect function](https://github.com/perak/meteor-mqtt-collection/#collectionmqttconnecturi-topics-options-mqttoptions):

```
Collection.mqttConnect(uri, topics, options, mqttOptions)
```

> "where `mqttOptions` is an object that is supplied to `mqtt.connect([url],options)` in the MQTT.js library for configuring the underlying options of the MQTT.js-client. [See the docs](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js#client)."

So far my Meteor test-code looks like this:

```
Goals = new Meteor.Collection('dbGoals');

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Goals.insert({ 
    topic: "goals", 
    message: "Hello world from Meteor Web Client", 
    broadcast: true 
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    Goals.mqttConnect("m10.cloudmqtt.com", ["goals"], {
      insert: true,
      raw: true
    },
    { servers: [{ host: 'm10.cloudmqtt.com', port: 12310 }],
      clientId:"uniqueIdforEachMqttClient",
      username: "myMqttUserName",
      password: "myMqttUserPass",
      clean:false
    });
```

And gets the following error:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.10\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:245
                                            throw(ex);
                                                  ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of null
at Object.connect (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\perak_mqtt-collection\1.0.4\npm\node_modules\mqtt\lib\connect\index.js:62:35)
at [object Object].Mongo.Collection.mqttConnect (packages/perak_mqtt-collection/packages/perak_mqtt-collection.js:37:1)
at E:\Data\Projects\Project2016\design\sw\mqttColl\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:249:5
at mqttColl.js:25:11
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Your application is crashing.
```

The line `mqttColl.js:25:11` is:

```
Goals.mqttConnect("m10.cloudmqtt.com", "goals", {
```

I know the object with my `servers:` options works with [MQTT.js](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js) running on Node and CloudMQTT, but I'm not sure that I've got the `mqttConnect()` function parameters entered correctly for the `perak` Meteor package.  For starters, it seems unlikely that the MQTT broker's URL would be needed in multiple places nor that the topic `goals` should be in brackets, but I'm just not clear on the parameter syntax.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add protocol into the URL: `mqtt://m10.cloudmqtt.com`.